# Retrieving process running dir from PID

Tags: c++, windows

Trying to retrieve the running directory of a process using the PID. I am obtaining the PID using `FindWindow()` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` which results in the same process ID as shown in task manager, so I assume it to be correct.

When using `GetModuleFileNameEx()`, instead of resulting in a path, I get what seems to be a memory address.

```
auto wnd = FindWindow(nullptr, L"prog");
while (wnd == nullptr)
{
    wnd = FindWindow(nullptr, L"prog");
}

TCHAR fBuf[MAX_PATH]; // buffer for path
DWORD procId; // process id
GetWindowThreadProcessId(wnd, &procId); // get process id
std::cout << procId << std::endl; // results in correct pid
auto procHdl = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, procId); // create handle for process
if (procHdl != NULL) {
    if (GetModuleFileNameEx(procHdl, 0, fBuf, MAX_PATH) == 0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get module filename." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Module filename is: " << fBuf << std::endl;
    }

    CloseHandle(procHdl);
}
```

Sample output is:

```
10488
Module filename is: 008CF93C
```

I have had the same result using `GetProcessImageFileNname()` too.

Comment: You should use `std::wcout` while printing wchar

Comment: Do not use TCHAR, that stopped making sense a decade ago.  Right now that macro turns fBuf into wchar_t[] and std::cout doesn't know how to display it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the directory of a program, first use GetModuleFileNameEx to get the program path, and your directory will start from the first character to the last backslash found.

Example:

Program is: "C:\Windows\notepad.exe";
Directory is: "C:\Windows";

In code:

```
DWORD pid = 104;
CHAR ProgramFile[MAX_PATH];
std::string DirectoryPath;
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ|PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
GetModuleFileNameExA(hProcess, NULL, ProgramFile, MAX_PATH);
DirectoryPath = ProgramFile;
DirectoryPath = DirectoryPath.substr(0, DirectoryPath.find_last_of('\\'));
std::cout << "ProgramFile: " << ProgramFile << endl;
std::cout << "Directory: " << DirectoryPath.c_str();
```